# $ABC$ is a right-angled triangle.

Tags: inequality

Consider three real numbers $a \geq b \geq c > 0$. If $(a^x - b^x - c^x)(x - 2) > 0$
for any rational number $x \neq 2$, show that

(i) $a, b$ and $c$ can be the lengths of the three sides of a triangle
$ABC$;

(ii) $ABC$ is a right-angled triangle.

**Try**

put $x = 1$ imples (i). I have no idea how to proceed for (ii)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the function $f(x)=a^x-b^x-c^x$. It is true that $f(x)>0$ for $x>2$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x<2$. Since f is a continuous function in real numbers, it follows that $f(2)=0$, which means that $a^2=b^2+c^2$, so $a, b, c$ are sides of an orthogonal triangle $ABC$.